# Stripping a list in a .txt to get specific value

Tags: python, sorting, text, text-files

I would like to sort the file 'Class1Scores' from highest to lowest. I have used a .txt to save the contents in the following way.

```
['jim', [0, 0, 8]]
['cllivus', [0, 0, 2]]
['fdfdgfr', [0, 0, 2]]
```

When sorted the output should be :

```
    jim, 8
    cllivus, 2
    fdfdgfr, 2
```

Here is the code I have used to develop the task:

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open("Class1Scores.txt") as f:
    srt = sorted(map(literal_eval, f), key=lambda x:max(map(int, x[1])), reverse=True)
    print(srt)
```

I am kind of still confused on how to order this in the same way as the .txt file above?The code works but outputs the data like this:

```
[['jim', [0, 0, 8]], ['cllivus', [0, 0, 2]], ['fdfdgfr', [0, 0, 2]]]
```

Comment: You would really benefit from using a dict storing the data as json

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post for how to ask better questions, which will help people give you better answers. In particular, add the code of what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing the data in a *dict* with user as key, their scores as values and to  [*json*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) the data to file but to sort your data in current format you can use `ast.literal_eval` to get the data back into lists, sort using the max score as the key and specifying `reverse=True` to sort from highest to lowest:

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open("in.txt") as f:
    srt = sorted(map(literal_eval, f), key=lambda x:max(map(int, x[1])), reverse=True)
```

Which will give you:

```
 [['jim', [0, 0, 8]], ['cllivus', [0, 0, 2]], ['fdfdgfr', [0, 0, 2]]]
```

If you want the names sorted alphabetically for a tie you need to change the logic slightly specifying -max and the name as the value to use in a tie removing `reverse=True` in this case:

```
 key=lambda x: (-max(map(int, x[1])), x[0])
```

You should be able to figure the rest out.

Comment: Is there a way to strip it and just take the highest scores for each user?

Comment: @joe, the max of each score list is the highest for each user, you already have the data sorted so how do you think you would get what you want?